# Import acceptable in if __name__ == '__main__' section?

Tags: python, pep8

Is it acceptable to put an `import` statement at the top of an `if __name__ == '__main__'` section, rather than the top of the script, if the module is only used when the script is directly executed?

Example:

```
def open_as_clean_list(filename):
    list = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            li = line.rstrip()
            if not li.startswith("#") and li:
               list.append(li)
        return list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import random

    first = open_as_clean_list("first.txt")
    second = open_as_clean_list("second.txt")
    print(random.choice(first) + ' ' + random.choice(second))
```

As you can see, `random` is only needed if the code is run directly. Is best practice to import anyway, or to only import if directly executed? Does it make a difference what the module actually is?

Comment: What is wrong with normal way?

Comment: Should I be concerned about importing modules I don't actually use? I know this example uses something in the standard library, but if I introduce a dependency on a third-party module would it be different?

Comment: It really does not any affect on your program actually.I importing 15-20modules even Im just going to print "hello world". So import them at the top :-)

Comment: [The style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) is clear: *"Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants."* FWIW, when I have short scripts like this I do sometimes put an `import` for testing in `if __name__ == '__main__':`, but for most things a separate `test_foo.py` will contain any test-only imports. This also avoids dependency issues - the main code doesn't require e.g. `import pytest`, so the end user only needs to install it if they want to `python setup.py test`.

Comment: Also you cant know a third party module is will be a problem or not if you use it after __main__ part? So the best way is normal one in my opinion

Comment: If you are really concerned about this you could declare your function somewhere else (another file). Import the function in this file. Put the random import at the top, code all of the job in `__name__` ... in a run function and only call this run function in the `__name__` block. It is often coded like that.

Comment: @qqvc *"importing 15-20 modules"* just to `print 'hello world'` is also a bad idea; you shouldn't have unused imports, it fills your namespace and makes the code harder to follow for no reason at all. The OP is right to try to minimise unused `import`.

Comment: I think it's perfectly acceptable to put imports in the section guarded by `if __name__ == '__main__'`, perhaps even preferable.  This communicates to future readers of the module that those imports have nothing to do with the design of the module and only with when it is run standalone.

Comment: It's fine and keeps the imported name out of the module's namespace when it's imported by another script. If you really want it at the beginning, note that it's possible to have more than one `if __name__ == '__main__':` in the script, just put one at the top, too.

Comment: I think it's fine- just be careful not to use any of the imported modules outside of the if block (like in the function for instance)